# Замена кавычек в строке

Tags: java, строки

Есть такой код:

```
for (User user : userList) {
     String oneLine = user.getDepName();
     bw.write(oneLine);
     bw.newLine();
}
```

В итоге в строке `oneLine` хранится такое значение `Офис "Центральный"`. Каким образом в можно заменить все `"` на `""`, чтобы в итоге было `Офис ""Центральный""` `user.getDepName().replaceAll("\"","\"\"");` не помогло?

Comment: `replaceAll` возвращает новую строку, а не изменяет текущую. Возможно, проблема в этом.

Comment: у меня все получилось https://ideone.com/FxDyhh
приведите ваш код, вдруг там ошибка.

Comment: @PavelParshin, да, в этом и есть проблема. Возможно ли это как-то обойти, чтобы замена корректно выполнялась?

Comment: @S.Ivanov  `user.setDepName(user.getDepName().replaceAll("\"", "\"\"")) ;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод `replaceAll` возвращает новую строку, а не изменяет текущую. Поэтому просто необходимо устанавливать новое значение:

```
String name = user.getDepName().replaceAll("\"","\"\"");
user.setDepName(name);
```

Такое поведение объясняется тем, что строки являются неизменяемыми. Из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> Strings are constant; their values cannot be changed after they are created

Comment: А зачем бедного юзера-то менять? Автору изменённая строка нужна была в отдельной переменной `oneLine`, так что `String oneLine = user.getDepName().replaceAll("\"","\"\"");` было бы достаточно.